# In the implemention of urcu-qsbr, is there any mechanism to ensure the thread offline/online is visible to writer-thread?

Tags: concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers, lock-free, rcu

In the implementation of urcu-qsbr, users can use `urcu_qsbr_thread_online` and `urcu_qsbr_thread_offline` to mark a critical section for reading.

Here's [offline/online](https://github.com/urcu/userspace-rcu/blob/81270292c23ff28aba1abd9a65f0624b657de82b/include/urcu/static/urcu-qsbr.h#L186)

Writers then use `urcu_qsbr_synchronize_rcu` to check whether the thread is online (ACTIVE) and whether the thread-local counter matches the shared counter to confirm whether the thread has seen the previous modifications.

Here's [wait_for_readers](https://github.com/urcu/userspace-rcu/blob/81270292c23ff28aba1abd9a65f0624b657de82b/src/urcu-qsbr.c#L144)

However, is there a potential scenario where a thread, after going offline, immediately goes online and reads old data, while the writer has not timely detected this thread is online, leading to the erroneous recycling of data?
Is there any mechanism to ensure this?
From my understanding, memory barriers can only ensure the visibility of the order of operations in a thread, but cannot guarantee the visibility of modifications within a bounded time frame between threads.

In my understanding, the concepts of online and offline in urcu-qsbr seem analogous to registering and unregistering, requiring a mutex-like mechanism to ensure synchronization between reader threads and writer threads.

Comment: "guarantee the visibility of modifications within a bounded time frame between threads.": This is always guaranteed for `_Atomic` types in C11, with or without memory barriers.  It's unclear whether the calls in this code end up working with C11 atomics, or are faking it with `volatile` in the old-fashioned way, but it's also the case that real architectures do ensure that any store to memory becomes globally visible without undue delay.

Comment: The code employs a seq_cst (sequentially consistent) barrier, which I believe provides the necessary guarantee.